# Comparing Two Values b/w Different Google Sheets & Importing Different Values if Match

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Apologies if this is a repeat question.  I've looked everywhere and have some of the answer, but not all of it; and I'm hoping it's a common enough use case that someone here can help.  Here's the fact pattern:

I have two complete different g/Sheet files -- `file_1` & `file_2`. These files have some column fields in common, so what I'd like to do is compare `Col A` in both sheets, and if `Col A` matches, then import the values located in columns from `file_1` to `file_2`

Thus, for example, it would look like this:

- If `Col_A` of `file_2' matches` Col_A`of`file_1`, then import values living in` Col_C`,` Col_E`,` Col_G`from`file_1`to`file_2`in the same row where`Col_A` matched.

What I've tried so far is an Imortrange() and vlookup() but I've only been able to get them working separately, not nested. Any thoughts / suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
=INDEX(BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(ax,IF(ax="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ax,IMPORTRANGE("[SHEET ID]","[TAB_NAME]!A:G"),{3,5,7},))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try with this VLOOKUP, adapting the columns and URL:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,IMPORTRANGE(URL,"Sheet2!A:G"),{3,5,7},0),{"","",""})
```